# How to run external program on multiple cpu cores using python?

Tags: python, multicore, os.system, cpu-cores

I am trying to run multiple simulations on an external program, CalculiX, using python. I am aware that the python script can't run on multiple cpu cores but CalculiX is an external program which I am running through the os.system command.
I need to run the simulations on multiple cores to save time.

```
    os.system("ccx WireBend")
```

This is what I am using to run the external program and it works, it just takes a lot of time as the calculations are done using only one cpu.
So how can I run ccx on multiple cores?
I am using python 3.6

Comment: It seems like you should be handling the multiprocessing in the program you are trying to run, not in python in this case.

Comment: According to the documentation for CalculiX, it takes the number of cores to use from the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` so try setting that.

Comment: I have set OMP_NUM_THREADS to my amount of cores. When I run calculix independantly it uses all the cores but if I run it through python it only uses one

Comment: `os.system("export OMP_NUM_THREADS=10 && ccx WireBend")`

Comment: I tried that and it gives the following error: `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: try:  `import os`   &  `os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS']` and then execute the command  again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the environment variable into the terminal from where you are running your program or set it in the script as Below:

```
import os
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS']
OR
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '10'
```

then run

```
os.system("ccx WireBend")
```

Answer (score 0):

With `subprocess.Popen` you can open a subprocess asynchronously (i.e. control will return to python before the subprocess has finished).

Use it many times to spawn multiple subprocesses and then check if each of the processes has terminated.